# How to get user token with Azure AD app with MSAL.net?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-authentication

I'm using MSAL.net in my application. I have registered my application in Azure Active Directory and did rest of configuration which is required.

In my Web API, I have some endpoint call to get the logged in user's token.

Now if I want to get user token in my backend application, which is in .NET Core, with the MSAL.net library, which method will help me to get the user token?

How will I get the user's token? Which method of MSAL will return the user token?

I want to use that user token for downstream API calls

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [MSAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token) to acquired a user token to call a Web API, it caches it. If you are building a public client application and want to acquire a token, first call AcquireTokenSilent before calling AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword. In that application will not call AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword frequently and acquire token silently.

Ref doc - https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the MSAL side of things, in order to get an access token to pass to an API, you have to request a [scope](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/getting-an-access-token-in-azure-ad-b2c-620c0790b964).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, user access tokens (the ones used to gain access to a resource/API) are obtained by an app registration on behalf of the user from a front-end application. If you want a (middle) API to retrieve an access token on behalf of the user and call a downstream API, you can use the [OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) Take a look to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph) on how to implement it using MSAL. Don't worry about having it a desktop client, the important part is the middle and down stream API.

Also, take a look to these samples for standard scenarios:

- [Web app that signs in users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-overview?tabs=aspnetcore)
- [A web app that authenticates users
  and calls web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview)

Comment: var token = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
is this correct way to get user token ?

Comment: and another way  userAssertion = new UserAssertion(userAccessToken.ToString().Replace("Bearer ", ""), "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer");  
  var result = await application.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, userAssertion).ExecuteAsync();
                string accessToken = result.AccessToken; so which is correct

Comment: Both are correct but serve different purposes. First will get a user access token. Second will use the former to obtain a new one for a downstream api using the OBO flow.